# Embedding base14 fonts in PDF created using pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I created a PDF using `txfonts`. But the base 14 fonts (Times-Roman, Times-Italic etc.) are not embedded  in the PDF. Could somebody help me to solve this issue? The font information in my PDF is as given below:

```
 name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Roman                          Type 1            no  no  no      14  0
Times-Roman                          Type 1            no  no  no      15  0
Times-Italic                         Type 1            no  no  no      16  0
LCHINT+NimbusRomNo9L-Medi            Type 1            yes yes no      17  0
```

In the `pdfmaps.tex` which I have the following entries:

```
\pdfmapfile{=acrobat-std-urw-kb.map}
\pdfmapfile{=psfonts.map}
\pdfmapfile{=txr.map}
```

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays the base fonts are included by default. You can enable/disable this by setting `pdftexDownloadBase14 true` / `pdftexDownloadBase14 false` in updmap.cfg and then regenerate the map files. You can temporarly (at least on miktex) switch by using `\pdfmapline{pdftex_dl14.map}` / `\pdfmapline{pdftex_ndl14.map}` in your document.

But if your system is old (`psfonts.map` sounds old) things can be different there. At first uncomment simply the `\pdfmapfile` commands and look what your pdftex does as default. If it doesn't work then, you should sent informations about your tex system and version.

Answer (score 2):

The PDF specification requires that a PDF viewer/printer/whatever *must* have the base 14 fonts embedded. Because of this, there is not need for an application to embed those fonts in a document.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts

Comment: @Claran McHale: Certain variants of PDF, such as PDF/A, and certain printers require that all fonts be embedded, in order to be sure that the file prints exactly as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working solution:

http://www.grassbook.org/neteler/highres_pdf.html

-> 3 Embedding fonts in PDFLateX

You created your PDF document with "pdflatex" and need to deliver it to your publisher but they complain that the fonts are not embedded? There is an easy solution to this. Note that all tricks with setting "pdftexDownloadBase14" to true etc failed for me. So, simply do this:

convert to Postscript:

```
pdftops main.pdf main.ps
```

reconvert to PDF but enforce font embedding (note, hyperlinks will not survive):

```
ps2pdf14 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dEmbedAllFonts=true main.ps main2.pdf
```

verify:

```
pdffonts main.pdf
```

Now all fonts should be embedded and your publisher happy.