# ps2pdf produces unreadable text with gnuplot epslatex terminal

Tags: eps, gnuplot, ps2pdf

I'm using the `gnuplot` `epslatex` terminal to generate LaTeX files which I then convert to `.pdf` files using `latex`→`dvips`→`ps2pdf`. The `.ps` file produced by `dvips` is fine (the first image). However, once I run `ps2pdf` on the file, it garbles the text (second image). What could be causing this issue?

[image: postscript file generated by <code>dvips</code>]

[image: pdf file generated by <code>ps2pdf</code>]

The gnuplot code used to generate the latex file looks like this:

```
reset

set terminal epslatex size 5.0,3.5 standalone header "\\usepackage{cmbright}\n" color colortext
set output '$0.tex'

# Line styles
set border linewidth 2
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#FF0000' linetype 1 linewidth 3 # red
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#FF8080' linetype 1 linewidth 2 # ltred
set style line 3 linecolor rgb '#00FF00' linetype 1 linewidth 3 # green
set style line 4 linecolor rgb '#80FF80' linetype 1 linewidth 2 # ltgreen

# Axis labels
set xlabel '$$t$$ (sec)'
set ylabel 'Events per second'

# Axis ranges
#set yrange [0:25]
set xrange[0:100]

# Tics in latex format
set format '$$%g$$'

# Key
set key right

plot "$1" index 0 using 1:2 with lines linestyle 1 title 'Underlying Function $$S_A$$',    "$1" index 1 using 1:2 with lines linestyle 2 title '$$s_A$$ counts',    "$2" index 0 using 1:2 with lines linestyle 3 title 'Underlying Function $$S_B$$',    "$2" index 1 using 1:2 with lines linestyle 4 title '$$s_B$$ counts'
```

The resulting LaTeX file is converted to a `.pdf` with

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex
dvips -o file.ps file.dvi
ps2pdf file.ps
```

I managed to fix the tics appearing in the `.pdf` by changing the tics format from `set format "%g"` to `set format "$$%g$$"`, which makes me think it might be something to do with that. I tried removing all math sections from the file, but the issue did not go away. For whatever reason, gnuplot complains (`"../plots/twostreams.plt", line 22: Invalid substitution $%`) if I only use a single $ to initiate math blocks, which appears to be the way to do it according to [this link](http://www.gnuplotting.org/introduction/output-terminals/). Incidentally, the example on that page can be converted to `.pdf` without any issues. The only difference that I can see is that I am using the `call` function of gnuplot to pass in files as parameters.

Edit: After a little further poking around, I found that changing the font to another font I'm using (the `libertine` package) ended up producing plots as expected. I've not tried anything new, but I am on a new system, and the `cmbright` font still does not render correctly.

Comment: Can you give code examples?

Comment: I've added the code used to generate the `.tex` file and convert it to a `.pdf`.

Comment: [May be fonts need embedding](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26372/15717). Hope you have seen [Gnuplot and PDFLatex question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41666/15717)