# Force usage of non-embedded base14 fonts only in pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Now pdfLaTeX creates files with embedded serif and sans fonts:

[image]

I want to generate PDF files which use only non-embedded Type 1 base14 fonts:

- Times instead Nimbus Roman
- Helvetica instead Nimbus Sans

There are many answers which suggests how to do the opposite (force font embedding), but I haven't found any solutions how to force usage of non-embedded fonts only.

I tried to set `pdftexDownloadBase14 false` as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15594/174718, but this option seems to be broken, as it resulted in usage of some custom generated Type 3 fonts:

[image]

How to force usage of non-embedded Type 1 fonts?

EDIT:

I have found a solution on Debian (which uses TeX Live):

1. Create file `/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` with the following contents:

   ```
   pdftexDownloadBase14 false
   ```
2. Run: `updmap-sys`.

On Windows (with MiKTeX) it does not work, results in Type 3 fonts being used as presented before.

Comment: In texlive you can use `\pdfmapfile{pdftex_ndl14.map}` in your document.